# /bin/sh script - how to tell if argument is either 1 or 2?

Tags: shell-script

I have been given a script to modify. It uses `/bin/sh` and I may not change that.

I want to check if an argument is an integer - specifically, either 1 or 2.

How do I do that, and cater for the parameter being either absent or a string, as well as an invalid integer?

Comment: Can you add more context? How do you currently check the arguments?

Comment: Sounds like homework. What have you tried, on which piece do you need assistance/explanation?

Comment: What representation of those integers do you want to allow? (0x1, +1, 001, 1.0, 1e0, 0x2p-1, 2 - 1, 18446744073709551617? Or only a literal single-character 1?)

Comment: "`How do you currently check the arguments?`" - the argument is being added & ought to be checked. Represent only as 1 or 2. Not homework. Workwork - and they won't let me use Python :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check whether an argument to a script is `1` or `2` you may simply use a case statement.

The code below assumes that you'd like to check `$1`:

```sh
case $1 in
    [12])
        # $1 is 1 or 2
        ;;
    *)
        # $1 is not 1 and not 2
esac
```

There is no real need to validate that the argument is a valid integer or not as you're only concerned about two specific values, and these can easily be validated as strings. The values of shell variables are always strings unless used in an arithmetic context, and there's no reason to do that here.

You may also use an explicit `if` statement:

```sh
if [ "$1" = '1' ] || [ "$1" = '2' ]; then
    # $1 is 1 or 2
else
    # $1 is not 1 and not 2
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the below link for checking argument value is an integer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210349/test-whether-string-is-a-valid-integer

and to check the absence of variable, let's say you are assigning your first argument to a variable

```
var=$1

 if [ ! -z "$var" ]; then
    echo "value is present"
 else
    echo "value is not present"
 fi
```

Comment: There is no need to check that the given argument is an _integer_ as it's easy to validate the argument as a string (there are only two valid strings, `1` and `2`).